# Configuring Internet links on different servers

Tags: load-balancing

In the company I work at we use two internet links which used to be balanced by a D-link router, but the router recently failed.

To temporarily solve the problem I have set up one of the links internet on a Windows Server 2003 machine. Now I would like to take the 2nd internet link and assign it to our Windows Server 2008 machine.

I know how to link the two machines to their different internet connections, but is it possible to set up load balancing between the two links? It needs to be something automatic, so that if Link A fails, then Link B is use automatically.

Comment: What is this I don't even

Comment: I gave a gallant effort at making sense of it, but the last paragraph is beyond my ability to understand and make sense of. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way (and most efficient) of doing this is to connect both links to the same box.
If you where happy with your d-link router, you can just install Linux on a box and use it as a Gateway for your company. I have used [ClearOS](http://www.clearfoundation.com/Software/overview.html) and [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org) for that, the first one being the easier to setup.

Comment: I'm creating a virtual machine with ClearOS pfSense and I just put an answer on the use.

anyway thank you